# Unable to execute ColumnTransformer function

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

I was trying to pre-process data. I filled the missing values. But when I tried to encode the categorical data into integers, the X dataset got encoded correctly but I'm getting an error in column y. There are not much articles on this topic as of yet. Please help.

- Please check the attached error image, the original dataset and the error is available in the image.
- The original dataset:

```
   Country   Age   Salary Purchased
0   France  44.0  72000.0        No
1    Spain  27.0  48000.0       Yes
2  Germany  30.0  54000.0        No
3    Spain  38.0  61000.0        No
4  Germany  40.0      NaN       Yes
5   France  35.0  58000.0       Yes
6    Spain   NaN  52000.0        No
7   France  48.0  79000.0       Yes
8  Germany  50.0  83000.0        No
9   France  37.0  67000.0       Yes
```

- Python Code:

````
# Importing the libraries
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

# Importing the dataset
dataset = pd.read_csv('Data.csv')
x = dataset.iloc[:, :-1].values
y = dataset.iloc[:, 3].values

# Taking care of missing data
from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer
imputer = SimpleImputer(missing_values = np.nan, strategy = 'mean')
imputer = imputer.fit(x[:, 1:3])
x[:, 1:3] = imputer.transform(x[:, 1:3])

# Encoding categorical data
# Encoding the Independent Variable
#from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder 
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer

from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder

ohe = OneHotEncoder()

ct = ColumnTransformer(
    [('one_hot_encoder', ohe, [0])],
    remainder='passthrough'
)

print(dataset)
x = np.array(ct.fit_transform(x), dtype=np.int)
y = np.array(ct.fit_transform(y), dtype=np.int)```

[error image][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/YPR66.png
````

Comment: What error are you getting? Can you show us what `y` looks like?

Comment: @ignoring_gravity y is the last column of the dataset. For the complete dataset, please refer the attached image.

Comment: Thanks :) can you copy-and-paste your data into your question? Just the top part that's in your image is enough. Then I can run it and will show you a fix

Comment: @ignoring_gravity Just the top part of the image is enough. 

   Country   Age   Salary Purchased
0   France  44.0  72000.0        No
1    Spain  27.0  48000.0       Yes
2  Germany  30.0  54000.0        No
3    Spain  38.0  61000.0        No
4  Germany  40.0      NaN       Yes
5   France  35.0  58000.0       Yes
6    Spain   NaN  52000.0        No
7   France  48.0  79000.0       Yes
8  Germany  50.0  83000.0        No
9   France  37.0  67000.0       Yes

Comment: Can you paste it into your question so formatting isn't lost?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`y` is your target variable, i.e. what you are trying to predict. It's a one-dimensional array, and if you call `y.shape`, you get

```
>>>y.shape
(10,)
```

This is why you can an index error - `y.shape[1]` is out-of-bounds.

You shouldn't be one-hot-encoding your target variable - instead, target-encode it. That is to say, replace your last line with:

```
y = pd.Categorical(y).codes
```

Then `y` will be

```
array([0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1], dtype=int8)
```

where `0` corresponds to "not purchased" and `1` to "purchased"

Comment: So, basically OHE is used for an array and here in my case y is a single column (so not an array) and that is why OHE is not working on y. Did I understood it correctly?

Comment: `y` is an array, but it's one-dimensional. `x`, on the other hand, is 2-dimensional, and so `x.shape[1]` is defined

Comment: That's right - if you look at the [docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html#sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.fit), under `.fit`, it says "X array-like, shape [n_samples, n_features]" - so they're expecting 2 dimensions (one for n_samples, another for n_features)

Comment: Thanks for the quick help. Upvoted your answer, but it wont be visible as I'm new in stacksoverflow.

Comment: That's fine, I'm happy to help :)